# Android crash in some actions when Instant run is turn off

Tags: android, crash, apk

I have very strange problem. When I have instant run turn on, everything works fine. But when I turn off the instant run, some actions crash my application. I cant debug it because if I comment some lines or use try-catch my aplicattion still crash. The same problem is when I make apk and try run it on my phone. My aplication crush on some action, and  I can not check what is wrong. Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004581/android-app-crashes-frequently-with-instant-run

Comment: out of topic...

Comment: were you able to figure out the problem?